# How do I use mockfirebase for my angular2 typescript unit test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, firebase, angular

How do you mock firebase using mockfirebase for firebase unit tests?

I'm using typescript and angular2 for this unit test.

**Here's one of my tests I would like to change to mockfirebase from firebase:**

```
 import { it, iit, describe, expect, inject, injectAsync, beforeEachProviders, fakeAsync, tick } from 'angular2/testing';
 import { FirebaseService } from '../app/firebase-service';

 describe('Firebase Service Calls', () => {

      it('log out user from Firebase', () => {
          let ref = new Firebase("https://markng2.firebaseio.com");
          let service = new FirebaseService();

          spyOn(service.ref, 'unauth');
          service.logOut();

          expect(service.ref.unauth).toHaveBeenCalled();
      })

 });
```

I want to change this line: "let ref = new Firebase("https://markng2.firebaseio.com");"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the `Firebase` class/function, `MockFirebase` is available on the `window`.

You can use `MockFirebase.override()` in your `beforeEach` function or in a fixture.

```
describe('Firebase Service Calls', () => {

      beforeEach(() => MockFirebase.override());

      it('log out user from Firebase', () => {
          let ref = new Firebase("https://markng2.firebaseio.com");
          ref.unauth();
          ref.flush(); // flush out the async action
          expect(ref.getUser()).toEqual(null);
      });
 });
```

When a user is authenticated a calling `ref.getUser()` will return the current user. The test above checks that the returned value from `ref.getUser()` is null when the user is logged out.

[Check out the documentation on authentication and MockFirebase.](https://github.com/katowulf/mockfirebase/blob/master/tutorials/authentication.md)

Comment: Any reason why you removed this as the accepted answer?

Comment: The beforeEach(() => MockFirebase.override()); doesnt work.

I get cannot find name "MockFirebase".
And "Flush" does not exist on type Firebase.

2 issues with the above answer?

Comment: It looks like you're not properly including MockFirebase. It's an external third party library, so it needs to be individually included.

Comment: Do I need to import it at the top of my tests?
If so where do I import it from?

Comment: It depends on how you're running the test suite. It's a dependency so it's either included in index.html or the Karma configuration.

Comment: I have a folder called mockfirebase in my node_modules.
How would I import that so I can use mockfirebase.

This is the link to it in the karma config: 
      {pattern: 'node_modules/mockfirebase/browser/mockfirebase.js', included: true, watched: true},

Comment: Notice that you're not importing Firebase? Like I mentioned, it's attached the window or globals depending on the environment. Wherever you're including Firebase that's where you include MockFirebase as well. You should also make sure you explicitly state MockFirebase as a dependency on your package.json.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96999/discussion-between-angularm-and-david-east).

Comment: I've messaged in the chat popup

Comment: Still doesn't work even though I've referenced the mockfirebase library in my karma config, any other ideas?

Comment: Not sure, I'd have to see your config, and that would be out of the scope of this question. But if it were configured, this code would work.